# Computer boots only to /dev/sda6:clean,

Tags: boot, gui

My Optiplex 9010 boots to a black screen with the text
/dev/sda6: clean, ***** files, ***** blocks
(/dev/sda6 is my 250GB Ubuntu partition, I dual boot with windows 10)

The background is I tried to install anbox using the instructions here: https://techpiezo.com/linux/install-anbox-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

I then uninstalled it, and uninstalled dbus-x11 too.

The problem arose the next time I rebooted.
I reinstalled dbus-x11 and tried all the steps here: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/

Executing sudo service gdm3 status   gives the result:

```
Loaded: loaded (/et/init.d/gdm3; generated)
        Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-06-28 11:41:00 IST; 2min ago
        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
        Process: 949 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/gdm3 start (code=exited status=0/SUCCESS)
Jun 28 11:41 <name> systemd[1] Starting LSB: GNOME Display Manager
Jun 28 11:41 <name> systemd[1] Started LSB: GNOME Display Manager
```

That was working at ctrl+alt+F2 tty. Returning to ctrl+alt+F7 shows the system is still at /dev/sda6: clean, ***** files, ***** blocks

The output of `Xorg -configure` throws up some more possible relevant info. Selecting a few lines:

```
xf86EnableIOports: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(++) Using config file: "/home/bloch/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
(II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.

Xorg is not able to detect your mouse.
Edit the file and correct the Device.
Xorg has configured a multihead system, please check your config.
Your xorg.conf file is /home/block/xorg.conf.new
To test the server run 'X -config /home/bloch/xorg.conf.new'
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Also: what error messages do you get when you do `startx` from tty2?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04
startx gives me a deep blue screen with functioning mouse pointer!!! Nothing else apparently ...

Comment: What exactly is in `/home/bloch/xorg.conf.new`? It mentions a multihead system, which you yourself don't mention in your question. Perhaps simply remove or rename your `xorg.conf.new` file. My 20.04 system starts up happily without one.

Comment: The xorg.conf.new file is similar to a sample xorg.conf file I found online. I deleted it, rebooted, and got back to the same /dev/sda6/:clean message.
I ran Xorg -config and it recreated the xorg.conf.new file.
Maybe the anbox installation changed my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d or is the cause of that "multihead system" message

Comment: So is there anything suspicious in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`? A brand new file, or one that points to `anbox`, that you could remove? FWIW I've got these: `10-amdgpu.conf, 10-quirks.conf , 10-radeon.conf,  40-libinput.conf,  70-wacom.conf`.

Comment: Yes, they're exactly the ones I have! And the dates on the files are all over a year old.
I'm baffled by this, but still think the "multi head system" is the best clue.

Comment: Other things to try: look in `./xsession-errors` (if it's recent) and/or remove any old `.Xauthority` files.

Comment: The xsession-errors file has about 80 lines and none of them explicitly say 'fail' or anything like that. The first line is 
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus  and there are a lot of dbus-update-activation-environment: lines

Comment: The file /.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log has some interesting lines: 
(**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
(WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using 'kbd' 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
(WW) Disabling Mouse()
... and some other failure messages

Comment: Are there any interesting messages indicated by "EE" as errors?

Comment: open /dev/fb0: permission denied

service gdm3 status gives 
Active: active (exited) since Mon ****** 15 minutes ago
which doesn't seem suspicious. It's like everything Xorg starts but has been directed somewhere else.

Comment: Re `/dev/fb0: permission denied` I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149985/startx-cannot-open-dev-fb0-permission-denied), perhaps it helps

Comment: The Xorg.wrap configuration file wrapper.config file in /etc/X11/ says it's a legacy file. So I think changing it would be a hack and might only lead to more problems down the road.
Thanks for you help Jos!! I don't know about you, but I'm ready to give up and use the bootable installation usb to do a repair install.  Is that the way to go do you think?

Comment: Before I'd do a repair install, I'd try (1) `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and (2) reinstalling `xserver-xorg` which basically reinstalls the whole X11 tree.

Comment: It didn't work. Still the same /dev/sda6: clean, **** blocks, ***** files message.
I uninstalled (apt-get purge) xserver-xorg and reinstalled it.